# Generate XML file from SharePoint 2010 Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, designer-workflow, xml

I have document library with field "`status`",

```
if "status" equal "Completed" 
then generate an XMLfile.
```

My question:

Can workflow allow the generation of files ? and if yes, could you give me some tips ?

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've never done so myself, but there are other questions/answers on this site that suggest that it should be possible.

[Creating Document with workflow: The file test.docx cannot be opened because there are problems with the contents](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/37491/creating-document-with-workflow-the-file-test-docx-cannot-be-opened-because-the)

The key seems to be setting up your library with a contentType that has an XML file as it's template, and then using the workflow to create a new item in that library.  Off the top of my head, I would think that you might run into difficulty if you need to edit the contents of that document however.

Good luck with this, let us know if you get it working!